# relation between .jpg and corresponding .asc file

Tags: python

I had a python assignment in which I was required to do certain operations on a map whose .jgp as well as .asc file was provided to me. I know that to every colored pixel in the map there is a numerical data assigned to it in the file. I was able to solve the questions in the assignment and generate the resulting .asc file that was required to be submitted. I just want to know if it is possible to assign colors to the numbers in the final .asc file and generate a jpg map of it. Also, please tell me how the assignment of the numbers to the pixels is done.

Comment: What is an `.asc` file? A signature?

Comment: .asc file contains the data related to the map image. Eg. If there is a patch in the map under rural category, then in the .asc file, the patch is represented by group of 1's in the exact same positions as that in the map. It's similar to the ascii art that we get to see these days. Except, its not an art, but has some meaning.